# unable to convert numpy array of array into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert a list of arrays to a dataframe(column names are not relevant to me).

Here's my original data:

```
array([array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.88 , 36340.176,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.577,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32),
       array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.88 , 36340.176,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.577,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32),
       array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.88 , 36340.176,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.577,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32),
       ...,
       array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.88 , 36340.176,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.577,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32),
       array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.89 , 36340.18 ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.576,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32),
       array([    0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   , 72995.88 , 36340.176,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
       12839.577,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,     0.   ,
           0.   ], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

I tried to convert it pandas using:

```
    pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(companyY))
0
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   0.0
... ...
287564720   0.0
287564721   0.0
287564722   0.0
287564723   0.0
287564724   0.0
```

It's missing the columns.

If I try without concat then I get:

```
pd.DataFrame((companyY))
0
0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
2   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
3   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
4   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
... ...
1643222 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1643223 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1643224 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1643225 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
1643226 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...
```

How can I get each item in the array of arrays to be it's own column..so if I have 100 arrays with 50 len arrays inside, then I'll have a 100 row dataframe with 50 columns?

Comment: Could you give a code to create your data? your data is probably in different shape than you think: `pd.DataFrame(np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 5, 6])]))` returns a dataframe with 3 columns and 2 rows. Perhaps your arrays are not in the same length. This can result your second example (where values are list instead of columns)

Comment: With the above sample, simply `pd.DataFrame(companyY)` worked for me.

Comment: @Roim I am afraid it will increase the complexity of the question. I have a very large application that generates this array and a few ML models that this is the final output of. Would def be confusing. If I do print(len(companyY[0])), I get 175 which is how many columns I expected.

Comment: @HenryYik I tried that again and in my original question, but I'm not getting unique columns for every item. Each array has 175 columns so I expect 175 columns in the dataframe

Comment: @Lostsoul then tries to recreate the problem with a different dataset. It's hard to reproduce that way, as it seems like your original code should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally `pd.DataFrame(companyY)` should work if you have all the inner array with same lengths, but as you said it is not working then this might suggest that you have some of the nested arrays with different lengths. So in order to create a dataframe a workaround would be to `map` each of the nested array to `list`

```
pd.DataFrame(map(list, companyY))
```

Or better,

```
pd.DataFrame([*companyY])
```